# Macro loop for deleting unwanted characters from cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in columns A and B. I need a macro that will loop through these columns and delete the text at the end. The columns look like this:

```
Column A    Column B
1234(AZ)    X1258Q156(ABCD)
3259(AZ)    81R58Q1V6(ABCD)
7849(AZ)    X1X58-156(ABCD)
1489(AZ)    XX258Q1(ABCD)
```

I need the macro to loop through column A and column B and remove the characters at the end. In column A's example, remove all (AZ) from it and in column B's example remove all (ABCD) from it. The text length will vary in column A and column B. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write the loop and insert the value into the range, but this will do what you want within the loop:

```
Range().Value = Left(Range().Value, InStr(1, Range().Value, Chr(40)) - 1)
```

Edit: `Left()` makes more sense...

Edit2: Find/Replace Method:

```
Range(ENTIRE RANGE HERE).Replace("(*)", "", LookAt:=xlPart)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngCell As Range

str1 = "(AZ)"
str2 = "(ABCD)"

'Set rngTemp
Set rngTemp = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'You range goes here

'Loop through range and replace string
For Each rngCell In rngTemp

    If InStr(1, rngCell, str1) > 0 Then
        rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str1, "")
    End If

    If InStr(1, rngCell, str2) > 0 Then
        rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str2, "")
    End If

Next rngCell
```

Answer (score -1):

This code should work for you. Assuming your code has the column you are working on and the text you want to remove.

```
Sub YourSub()
    RemoveCharactersFromComumn "A", "(AZ)"
    RemoveCharactersFromComumn "B", "(ABCD)"
End Sub

Sub RemoveCharactersFromComumn(col As String, find As String)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(col + ":" + col)

    rng.Replace What:=find, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```